# Asp.net Entity Framework Insert Duplicate PK Exception

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I write a service can reach values ​​of weekly up to date exchange rates.
But ​​I get an error when sending the values to the database.I created a database model in Entity Framework. The associated database tables names are `CURRENCY` and `WEEKLY_VALUE`.

Related fields are `KOD` field in `CURRENCY` and `KOD` field in `WEEKLY_VALUE` table. `KOD` field in `WEEKLY_VALUE` is Foreing_key.

I get an error in this code:

```
    public void insertWeeklyCurrency(List<CURRENCY> currencyList)
    {
        myEntity = new CurrencyEntities();
        DateTime date = new DateTime();
        date = System.DateTime.Now;
        String day= date.DayOfWeek.ToString();
        if (!day.Equals("Sunday") && !day.Equals("Saturday"))
        {
            WEEKLY_VALUE weeklyCurrency;
            for (int i = 0; i < currencyList.Count; i++)
            {
                weeklyCurrency = new WEEKLY_VALUE();
                weeklyCurrency.KOD = currencyList[i].KOD;
                weeklyCurrency.TARIH = currencyList[i].TARIH;
                weeklyCurrency.DEGER = currencyList[i].F_SATIS;
                weeklyCurrency.CURRENCYReference.Value=currencyList[i];
                myEntity.AddToWEEKLY_VALUE(weeklyCurrency);
                myEntity.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

The error message:

> {"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_CURRENCY'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.CURRENCY'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

How can handle this error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach the elements in the currencyList to the context to let EF know that they already exist in the database, otherwise EF will try to insert them to the DB:

```
for (int i = 0; i < currencyList.Count; i++)
{
    myEntity.Currencies.Attach(currencyList[i]);
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get this error you are more than likely trying to insert something that is already in the table.

Besides the obvious, I need to see the schema to pinpoint where exactly the problem is. 
However,

weeklyCurrency.CURRENCYReference.Value=currencyList[i];

looks suspicious. If KOD is already a foreign key to the currency, what is this CURRENCYReference Value?

Comment: `CURRENCYReference` is a property generated by EF when you use entities derived from `EntityObject` (and not POCOs). Each reference navigation property `XYZ` has a related `XYZReference` property of type `EntityReference<T>`. It's "normal" but kind of oldfashioned EF.